# VPC access connector GCP - Cloudrun Services and AlloyDB different Regions

Tags: google-cloud-run, google-vpc

Quick Question, i am trying to configure a cloudrun service to be connected using AlloyDB on GCP.
The problem here is AlloyDB is in a different region than the others services, in this case central1, and services east1.

Is there any way to do the pairing between them?

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no connectivity issue. You use a serverless VPC connector to bridge the serverless world (where your Cloud Run live) with your VPC. Therefore, with default configuration, all the traffic going to a private IP will arrive in your VPC.

Then you have your AlloyDB peered with your VPC also. Because the VPC is global, as long as you are in the VPC (AlloyDB or Cloud Run), any service can reach any resources, whatever their location.

---

In fact, your main concern should be the latency and the egress cost.

Comment: Thanks so much for your response!
Have a great weekend!